# Unwanted bumps on rifle

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]So I'm making a model of a Kar98K and I'm currently working on the stock. And on the stock there are these bumps that really stand out and it's ruining that part of the mesh. Can someone recommend a solution?[image]

Comment: It looks like the mesh is more dense there, and that's causing more detail to appear when subsurfed. This is of course a guess, since I can't see your wireframe. Usually artists use denser geometry in places they want more edge detail, and such edge loops are called "holding loops". Examine your geometry and try to space out your mesh density more uniformly and you should be all set.

Comment: I've added my wireframe to the post.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, your mesh is too dense. Try dissolving some of those edge loops. Maybe even use a different reference image if that one is confusing. You don't need the subsurf that high while modeling either; it will probably add to your confusion.